Как переместить строки из StringBuilder обратно в String. Java
пишу программу которая записывает переменные String в StringBuilder, что бы сохранить их в файле. После мне нужно их достать и переместить обратно в те же String. Как это правильно сделать? И возможно ли вообще?
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String text = "text";
String text2 = "text2";
sb.append(text).append(" ").append(text2);
//и тут нужно в переменные записать те же значения
text = ?
text2 = ?


Зависит от того как строки складываются в StringBuilder.

Чтобы преобразовать содержимое StringBuilder в строку, достаточно вызвать его метод toString().  Но сама проблема не слишком понятна: 1) для чего "записывать" строки в StringBuilder, если их надо записать в файл? Что значит "переместить обратно в те же String"?  Уточните свою проблему, приведите минимальный пример кода и/или опишите, какой результат должен получиться.

@clay может, это в ответ поместить?

Эврика! ТС написал как он сохраняет значения в файл (сериализует) и спрашивает как их прочитать обратно (десериализовать). Хвалите меня за догадливость.

Прежде чем записывать строки в файл, можно использовать StringBuilder для форматирования текста. Больше я не вижу зачем его использовать. Ну, а для того, чтобы считать строки обратно, нужно писать парсер, который должен использовать данный формат для извлечения требуемых строк.

Если вы абсолютно уверены, что в текстах нет пробелов, то так:
public class Data {
    public String text;
    public String text2;

    public String save() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text = "text";
        String text2 = "text2";
        sb.append(text).append(" ").append(text2);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void load(String s) {
        String[] words = s.split(" ");
        text = words[0];
        text2 = words[1];
    }
}


а если есть пробелы?

Тогда сохраняйте JSON.

а где об этом по подробнее почитать можно?

Можно тут посмотреть пример https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial
